# initialising an array in C++

Tags: c++, arrays

I have a problem with initialising an array. The debugger tells me that `Left[s1]` gets some random int after some time (fx. `Left[2317]`), and then when it runs the next line: `Right[s2]`, and that is initialised as intended, `Left[s1]` all of a sudden becomes `"variable not available"`. Why is this case? What is happening behind the scenes?

```
void merge(int array[], int p, int q, int r) {

    int s1 = q;
    int s2 = r-q;
    int Left[s1]; //gets assigned random int at first, and then "variable not available"
    int Right[s2]; // works just fine
    // ...
```

Comment: what compiler do you use? `Left[s1]` and `Right[s2]` is illegal in standard c++. All arrays need their size known at compile time.

Comment: Variable length arrays, or VLA for short, such as `Left[s1]` and `Right[s2]` are a C thing, not a C++ thing. They are forbidden in pedantic C++ standard. It is highly unlikely that your compiler produces the `"variable not available"` message.

Comment: I am coding in VS code and use Clang compiler (I assume). Why is it not legal?

Comment: Try compiling with the `-Wall` and `-pedantic` flags to obtain more info from the compiler. A simple compilation command can look like: `clang++ -Wall source.cpp -std=c++17 -pedantic`.

Comment: They use the same approach here: https://www.programiz.com/dsa/merge-sort

Comment: It's not legal because C++ does not allow it. Your compiler allows it, but your compiler is not following the C++ rules (in this instance). Other compilers would reject that code.

Comment: @GoldenRetriever Obviously not a good site to learn C++ from if they give sample code that is not legal C++. Unfortunately C++ on the internet is often poor quality. The valid C++ method is to use `std::vector<int>` instead.

Comment: Thanks for letting me know that it's not a legal way of using C++. Nice to know for the future!
Could I however do the following instead to obtain a pointer to some storage? Would that be legal? For example:
    'int* Left = new int[s1]'

Comment: @GoldenRetriever That's perfectly legal, but vectors are a superior alternative. Using pointers directly brings many issues.